# Post Multipart file upload with json (text) and files (binary) as parts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, http, upload, multipart

I'm almost done with a multipart file upload but not quite. The API I am using requires two parts: a meta description (Json) and a file (File).

Here some of the Code:

```
File.open(file_path) do |image|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new(
    url.path,
    'metadata' => metadata_as_json_string,
    'attachment' => UploadIO.new(image, "image/jpeg", "image.jpg")
  )
```

The trouble I am having is with the 'metadata' part (metadata_as_json_string). Without it everything works fine, but the API requires meta information as json. It works if I save the json content in a file and use it as metadata-part. But my content is not coming from a file.

Any ideas how to provide the metadata without previously saving it in a file?

Thank you

Comment: What's the error when you are using a json string?

Comment: sadly I just get a INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR from the webservice, so no real hint, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution myself by using **StringIO**:

```
metadata_file = StringIO.new(metadata_as_json_string)

File.open(file_path) do |image|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new(
  url.path,
  'metadata' => UploadIO.new(metadata_file, "application/json"),
  'attachment' => UploadIO.new(image, "image/jpeg", "image.jpg")
)
```

Anyway thank you for your time